# List of dict to list of list python

Tags: python

I got the following list of dict points that i would like it to be a list of list in python.

```
points = [
{"x": 1, "y": 1},
{"x": 2, "y": 2},
{"x": 4, "y": 2},
{"x": 3, "y": 1},
{"x": 1, "y": 1},
{"x": 1, "y": 3},
{"x": 3, "y": 3},
{"x": 3, "y": 1},
{"x": 3, "y": 3},
{"x": 4, "y": 4},
{"x": 4, "y": 2},
{"x": 4, "y": 4},
{"x": 2, "y": 4},
{"x": 2, "y": 2},
{"x": 2, "y": 4},
{"x": 1, "y": 3},
{
```

i tried:

```
l = [points[n]['x'],points[n]['y']] for n in points
```

which give me the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-44-c60d18ea4de6>", line 1
l = [points[i]['x'],points[i]['y']] for i in points
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What result, exactly, are you looking for??

Comment: Your syntax error is caused because you need parentheses here, `(...., ....)`. But note you are iterating over `for i in points`... then you try to index into `points` with `i`, `points[i]`, but `i` is a *`dict`*, so that will throw a type error.... `i` is already what you want, so `[(d['x'], d['y']) for d in points]` is all you need

Comment: Please redo a tutorial on  list comprehensions. You want `[[i['x'], i['y']] for i in points]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through `points` so don't need to use indexing.

```
l = [[pairs['x'], pairs['y']] for pairs in points]
```

Answer (score 1):

You ended the brackets too early in the comprehension. Easy mistake. Although you also aren't accessing the inner dicts correctly. Use the following for more correct comprehension:

```
[d['x'], d['y'] for d in points]
```

or just map `dict.values` to the list:

```
list(map(dict.values, points))
```

This works as you only need the values in each dict. All have only x any y in them. Although this will only work if you're using python3.x and the values were all entered in x,y order.

Otherwise you can use `operator.itemgetter` instead of `dict.values`

```
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter('x', 'y'), points)
```

Comment: He hasn't specified this, but what if the order of the dictionary is not `x, y` but `y, x`?

Comment: I put that stipulation in at the end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[[i['x'], i['y']] for i in points]`